Filepond multiple files in one request react-filepond
I'm trying to get filepond running with the aim of sending multiple files in one request instead of one request for one file.
I achieved to send all files in a request but a request will be sent (with all files included as formData) for n files.
For two files I get response of:
POST /api/upload 200 in 11320ms
POST /api/upload 200 in 14739ms
Here is my code:
Thanks in advance :)
file-upload.tsx:
export default function FileUpload({
  jobDescription,
  jobPostingId
}: FileUploadProps) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<FilePondFile[]>([]);
  const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState('');

  let pond: FilePond | null = null;

  const handleProcessFiles: ProcessServerConfigFunction = (
    fieldName,
    file,
    metadata,
    load,
    error,
    progress,
    abort,
    transfer,
    options
  ) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (pond) {
      const files = pond.getFiles();
    }

    files.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append('files', file.file, file.file.name);
    });

    if (jobDescription && jobPostingId) {
      formData.append('jobDescription', jobDescription);
      formData.append('jobPostingId', jobPostingId);
    }

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/api/upload');

    request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
      progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
    };

    request.onload = () => {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
        load(request.responseText);
        setServerResponse(request.responseText);
      } else {
        error('Error uploading files');
      }
    };

    request.send(formData);

    return {
      abort: () => {
        request.abort();
        abort();
      }
    };
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (pond) {
      pond.processFiles();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FilePond
        ref={(ref) => {
          pond = ref;
        }}
        server={{
          process: handleProcessFiles
        }}
        allowMultiple={true}
        onupdatefiles={setFiles}
        credits={false}
        acceptedFileTypes={['application/pdf']}
        instantUpload={false}
      />
      <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Button>
    </>
  );
}

/api/upload/route.ts
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const formData: FormData = await req.formData();
  const uploadedFiles = formData.getAll('files');
  let fileName = '';
  let parsedText = '';
  let fileData = null;
  let fileNameOriginal = '';
  console.log('UPLOADED FILES: ', uploadedFiles);
  if (uploadedFiles && uploadedFiles.length > 0) {
    const uploadedFile = uploadedFiles[0]; // Changed from uploadedFiles[1]
    //console.log('Uploaded file:', uploadedFile);
    fileNameOriginal = uploadedFile.name;
    //console.log(fileNameOriginal);
    //console.log('FORM DATA: ', formData);

    // Check if uploadedFile is of type File
    if (uploadedFile instanceof File) {
      // Generate a unique filename
      fileName = uuidv4();

      // Convert the uploaded file into a temporary file
      const tempFilePath = `/tmp/${fileName}.pdf`;

      // Convert ArrayBuffer to Buffer
      const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(await uploadedFile.arrayBuffer());

      // Save the buffer as a file
      await fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, fileBuffer);

      // Store the file data as a bytea object
      fileData = `\\x${fileBuffer.toString('hex')}`;

      // Parse the pdf using pdf2json. See pdf2json docs for more info.
      const pdfParser = new (PDFParser as any)(null, 1);

      // Use a Promise to wait for the pdfParser_dataReady event
      parsedText = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', (errData: any) => {
          console.log(errData.parserError);
          reject(errData.parserError);
        });

        pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', () => {
          const rawText = (pdfParser as any).getRawTextContent();
          //console.log('Raw text:', rawText);
          resolve(rawText);
        });

        pdfParser.loadPDF(tempFilePath);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Uploaded file is not in the expected format.');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No files found.');
  }

  const jobDescription = formData.get('jobDescription')?.toString() || '';

  ...

  const responseData = {
    parsedText,
    fileData,
    fileName: fileNameOriginal
  };

  const response = new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(responseData), {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });

  return response;
}

UPDATE: I think I've figured it out (partially :D)
const onSubmit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (pond) {
      const files = pond.getFiles();
      files.forEach((file) => {
        formData.append('files', file.file, file.file.name);
      });
      if (jobDescription && jobPostingId) {
        formData.append('jobDescription', jobDescription);
        formData.append('jobPostingId', jobPostingId);
      }
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', '/api/upload');

     /* request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
        progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
      }*/

      request.send(formData);
    }
  };

Now it'll send one request with all files in it.
But now I still need to get the status updates of the file. In the UI (filepond container) it looks like the files were never uploaded.
